# How to prevent Android studio from opening the run tab every time I run the application

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I run the application the run tab will open which is annoying, how can I prevent this?

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you need to uncheck the `Activate tool window`

steps:

1-

[image]

2- Scroll down

[image]

Comment: I use AS 10 years yet I forgot again where this is....

Comment: For anyone whose in here in 2023. You need to scroll a bottom to see the activate tool window checkbox

Comment: I spent way too long looking for this, only to realize I needed to scroll down lol