# Where is "Activate tool window" button?

Tags: android, android-studio

According this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75399534/14368551) to prevent run window appearing after running an app you have to uncheck `Activate tool window`. But there isn't this button in the current version:
[image]

**Where can i find it ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *scroll down* further in this window. You can see the **scroll bar** on the right side. It's annoying, but it is there.

[image: Activate tool window button]